# Cell customization in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone

I want to make a table view in my iPhone Application.. In that table each shall contains 1 image, some text of line, some symbols, etc.. I don't now how to customize our cell of table. Please provide some help if you have..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a default UITableViewCell to do what you described by initializing the Cell (in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ) with the proper UITableViewCellStyle

e.g.:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...

return cell;
```

}

which gives you:
"A style for a cell with a left-aligned label across the top and a left-aligned label below it in smaller gray text. The iPod application uses cells in this style."
Also every kind of UITableViewCell has an image-property by default.

but here are some tutorials for building custom cells:

[Custom UITableViewCells with Interface Builder](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cell in Interface Builder.  Start with a UITableViewCell which acts like a view, and then add a UIImage, one or more labels, whatever containers to hold your symbols, etc.

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, load the nib and fill in the picture and labels, etc.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {      
        cell = myTableCell; // get the object from the outlet
        myTableCell = nil; // make sure this can't be re-used accidentally
    }


    // Set up the cell...
    cell.myViewController = self;
    // set up image and labels here
    return cell;
}
```